# How can I retrieve values of Custom Field Suite plugin nested loop one by one?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, custom-fields

I used Custom Field Suite to make a custom field using it's loop function and cannot get around retrieving the values one by one. The structure of the custom field is somewhat like this:

I'm just an amateur with regards to php so I haven't tried anything but scour the web for possible answer, but CFS has so little documentation on the web.

https://gyazo.com/6929bd0063d8a6ad0bd3881a368579d7

I would want to retrieve each post content on different parts of my php file. For example；post-content0 on top of the page and post-content5 on the last part of the page.